# Acceder a vista html con o sin estar logueado en Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

En mi $stateProvider tengo definido las vistas de mi aplicacion en el cual ciertas vistas requieren que el usuario este o no logueado. Hasta el momento esta trabajando de forma correcta. Pero el problema que tengo ahora es que tengo una vista la cual el usuario debe acceder con o sin login este es mi codigo:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('registro',{
                url:'/registro',
                templateUrl:'app/carpeta1/vista1.html',
                controller: 'registroCtrl',
                authenticate: true
            })
            .state('registro_emp',{
                url:'/registro_emp',
                templateUrl:'app/carpeta2/vista2.html',
                controller: 'registro_empCtrl',
                authenticate: false
            })
            .state('empresas', {
                url:'/empresas/:id_empresa',
                templateUrl:'app/carpeta3/vista3.html',
                controller: 'perfilEmpCtrl_sl',
                authenticate: true/false (aqui deseo llamar a una factoria la cual me devuelve si el usario esta o no logueado)
            })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    })
```

esta es mi factoria:

```
.factory("Autenticacion", function($cookies, $cookieStore)
{
    return{
        isAuthenticated : function()
        {
            var username = $cookieStore.get('username');
            if(typeof(username) != "undefined")
            {   
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

mi pregunta es como inserto la factoria que me devuelve mi estado de logueo en el state "empresas"> ya que esa vista puede ser visitada por el usuario con login o sin login

De antemano les agradezco

Answer (score 0):

Con esto consigues que antes de entrar haga el chequeo, si es correcto ejecutas lo que quieras.

```
.state('empresas', {
    url: '/empresas/:id_empresa',
    templateUrl: 'app/carpeta3/vista3.html',
    controller: 'perfilEmpCtrl_sl',
    onEnter: function($state, Autenticacion){

        if(Auth.isAuthenticated()){
            /*** Y aqui el codigo para cuando este autenticado ***/
        }
    }        

})
```

Esto lo uso para cuando entro en el login, al abrir una app si ya esta logeado porque su token no ha caducado lo reenvio a la pagina de inicio, en caso contrario ejecuto el controlador del login

Comment: y si quisiera implementar solo esto Autenticacion.isAuthenticated() ya que eso  me devuleve true o false, es posible?

Comment: En ese if ya tienes el true y el false. Para que sirve ese autenticate: true/false ¿?